# Number of ancestors of a precise node

Tags: xpath

As usual my question is simple but I dont seem to be able to do what I want :

```
<test targetAttribute="level 1">
   <test targetAttribute="level 2">
      <test targetAttribute="level 3">
         <test targetAttribute="level 4">
            <test targetAttribute="level 5">
            </test>
         </test>
      </test>
   </test>
</test>
```

I want to know how many ancestors have the `//test/@targetAttribute="level 5"` node.

I have been trying thousand things, nothing is working for me :

- `count(//test/@targetAttribute="level 5"/ancestor::*)`
- `//test/@targetAttribute="level 5"/count(ancestor::*)`
- `count(ancestor::*[//test/@targetAttribute="level 5"])`
- ...

I just don't seem to be able to find what I am looking at on google...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notion of ancestor is known for *element*, so, first, you need to find the target element which has `@targetAttribute="level 5"` :

```
//test[@targetAttribute='level 5']
```

From here, you should be able to modify the above XPath to return count of ancestor elements of the target element :

```
count(//test[@targetAttribute='level 5']/ancestor::*)
```

**<kbd>[`Demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/X9v2sO4i6)</kbd>**